# org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class java.net.Inet6Address is not supported in dialect DEFAULT

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

The static DSL function(s) for `row()` seem not to use the dialect used in the DSLContext.

I'm using postgres with jooq to query my database. I have a Binder for use with java objects of type `InetAddress`, which I am using successfully in other parts of my application. The dialect is correctly set to postgres when using the contextual DSL (DSLContext).

However, if I try to use static functions from the `DSL` class, the DEFAULT dialect is used and my Binder is not used.

Specifically, my problematic query in question looks like this:

```java
final var existingLinkRecords = asSeq(create
    .selectFrom(l)
    .where(row(l.FROM_IP, l.TO_IP).in(links.map(link -> row(link.from().ip(), link.to().ip())).asJava()))
    .fetch());
```

The previous code leads to the following exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class java.net.Inet6Address is not supported in dialect DEFAULT
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:884)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:823)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.getDataType(DSL.java:21760)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:19522)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.field(Tools.java:1209)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.row(DSL.java:20152)
...
```

The root of the problem seems to be this function from DSL:

```java
@Deprecated
@Support
public static <T> DataType<T> getDataType(Class<T> type) {
    return DefaultDataType.getDataType(SQLDialect.DEFAULT, type);
}
```

I could not find any way to construct `RowN()` objects other than using the DSL class.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8197, which has been fixed in jOOQ 3.11.10. What jOOQ version are you using?

Comment: thanks @LukasEder for you answer. i am using 3.11.7, but i just tried it with 3.11.11 and encountered the same problem. i think the problem is that the `T` values i am passing into `DSL.row(T, T)` are no `Fields` or other jooq-specific classes, but naked Inet6Address types, so the `DSL.row(T, T)` function has no way of obtaining the context. is there a way to get a context-aware version of `DSL` that can create `Row` objects? or is there any other way to do `where (a, b) in (('x', 'y'), ('z', 'n'))` where, x, y, z, n, are not `Fields` but values? :)

Comment: I see, you're right. You still have to update, though :-)

Comment: will do :) thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises from your call to

```java
row(link.from().ip(), link.to().ip())
```

Since `DSL.row()` is a static method, jOOQ 3.11 currently cannot "guess" what the appropriate data type binding for your custom types is, hence the exception.

As a workaround, there are various ways to attach a data type binding to your row expression. Since you have already attached it to your `row(l.FROM_IP, l.TO_IP)` columns, you can reuse those using [`DSL.val(Object, Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val-java.lang.Object-org.jooq.Field-)

```java
row(val(link.from().ip(), l.FROM_IP), val(link.to().ip(), l.TO_IP))
```

This should probably work out of the box in your case. I have created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8517

Comment: thank you, this method works and does exactly what i wanted!